# Gnuplot insert points in a parallel plot

Tags: gnuplot

I need create a parallel plot with lines and points using gnuplot.
Unfortunately either using

```
set style line 1 lc rgb 'blue' lt 1 lw 2 pt 7 ps 0.75 pi 5
```

or by setting pt ps and pi in plot command

Gnuplot do not insert any point.

I need to insert points to distinguish two line with the same color. 
They have to be the same color since they are of the same "family". Therefore, I can not simply change the colors :(

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Gnuplot simply cannot do this. In general, this would also crowd your axes since the points would all lay on  the axes. So you'll need to think of a different kind of visualization (use dark blue and bright blue to distinguish them). But without knowing the actual use case, this is only some guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unfortunately true that Gnuplot does not support this feature "out of the box", nevertheless should you need this just for some quick one-time production plot then there is a slightly dirty way how to do this. To be more specific, one can get the current source code of Gnuplot, in a more or less satisfactory way introduce this feature and generate the desired figure with the modified version of Gnuplot.

To illustrate the idea, let's assume that we want to parallel-plot following data file `data.dat` consisting of merely three "sets":

```
1 2 3
2 1 1
3 3 3
```

Inspired by the default Gnuplot demo `parallel.dem`, one would probably try to achieve this with a script `test.gpl` like this:

```
set title "Parallel Axis Plot" font ",15"

set terminal pdf
set output 'test.pdf'

set border 0
unset key
set xrange [] noextend
unset ytics

# use x-axis tic positions to label the axes
set xtics 1 format "axis %g" scale 0,0

# turn on axis tics for the parallel axes
set for [i=1:3] paxis i tics

plot 'data.dat' using 1:2:3 with parallel
```

However, this produces plot which will probably resemble:
[image]

Here, all lines are of the same type and color which is rather confusing. As a small upgrade, let's modify our input data file as follows:

```
1 2 3 5
2 1 1 6
3 3 3 7
```

and use slightly different plotting command

```
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2:3:4 with parallel lc var
```

This yields

[image]

The resulting figure looks a bit better but let's say that we do insist on having a plot with points. Simply adding something like `pt 1` does not work. Moreover, it produces a warning message: `"test.gpl", line 17: warning: No pointtype specifier allowed, here` suggesting that `parallel` style does not like any point specification at all.

### Dirty fix

To partially improve upon this, let's proceed as follows:

```
cd ${HOME}

#prepare a sand box directory
mkdir gpl
cd gpl

#download the latest version
wget -O gnuplot_latest.tgz http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/latest/download?source=files
tar -xzvf gnuplot_latest.tgz

cd gnuplot-5.0.0
./configure --prefix=${HOME}/gpl/local
make && make install
```

Here, we are assuming that our system already has all the necessary prerequisites for a successful build. For example on Ubuntu, this minimal-case scenario should probably require just the development packages of libpango and libreadline.

Now, we need to play a little bit with some of the source files stored in `${HOME}/gpl/gnuplot-5.0.0/src`. Namely, we have to

1. convince Gnuplot that the plotting style `parallel` likes points. For this it is sufficient to modify line `114` in `gp_types.h` and replace

   ```
   PARALLELPLOT = 32*PLOT_STYLE_BITS + PLOT_STYLE_HAS_LINE
   ```

   with

   ```
   PARALLELPLOT = 32*PLOT_STYLE_BITS + PLOT_STYLE_HAS_LINE + PLOT_STYLE_HAS_POINT
   ```
2. introduce the ability to plot points within the `parallel` style. To this end, one has to locate the function `plot_parallel` in file `graphics.c`. By default it looks like this:

   ```
   static void
   plot_parallel(struct curve_points *plot)
   {
       int i, j;
       int x0, y0, x1, y1;

       for (i = 0; i < plot->p_count; i++) {

       /* rgb variable  -  color read from data column */
       check_for_variable_color(plot, &plot->varcolor[i]);

       x0 = map_x(1.0);
       y0 = AXIS_MAP(PARALLEL_AXES+0, plot->z_n[0][i]);
       for (j = 1; j < plot->n_par_axes; j++) {
           x1 = map_x((double)(j+1));
           y1 = AXIS_MAP(PARALLEL_AXES+j, plot->z_n[j][i]);
           draw_clip_line(x0, y0, x1, y1);
           x0 = x1;
           y0 = y1;
       }

       }
   }
   ```

   Let's pimp it up a little bit:

   ```
   static void
   plot_parallel(struct curve_points *plot)
   {
       int i, j;
       int x0, y0, x1, y1;

       int point_type;
       struct termentry *t = term;

       for (i = 0; i < plot->p_count; i++) {

       /* rgb variable  -  color read from data column */
       check_for_variable_color(plot, &plot->varcolor[i]);
       point_type = plot->varcolor?((int)plot->varcolor[i]-1):plot->lp_properties.p_type;

       x0 = map_x(1.0);
       y0 = AXIS_MAP(PARALLEL_AXES+0, plot->z_n[0][i]);

      (*t->pointsize)(plot->lp_properties.p_size);
      (*t->point)(x0, y0, point_type);

       for (j = 1; j < plot->n_par_axes; j++) {
           x1 = map_x((double)(j+1));
           y1 = AXIS_MAP(PARALLEL_AXES+j, plot->z_n[j][i]);
           draw_clip_line(x0, y0, x1, y1);
           (*t->point)(x1, y1, point_type);
           x0 = x1;
           y0 = y1;
       }

       }
   }
   ```
3. and that's it! Now compile Gnuplot again with `make && make install` (invoked from directory `${HOME}/gpl/gnuplot-5.0.0`). The output generated with `${HOME}/gpl/local/bin/gnuplot ${HOME}/gpl/test.gpl` (using plotting command `plot 'data.dat' using 1:2:3:4 with parallel lc var ps 1.5`) should resemble this:

[image]

### Explanation

1. modification in `gp_types.h` ensured that the point size specification `ps 3` used in the final plot is not ignored (and is accessible in the `plot_parallel` function)
2. in the `plot_parallel` function, we need to introduce a pointer to the global terminal variable, i.e., `struct termentry *t = term;`. This is then used later for the actual plotting of points.
3. in the `for` loop which iterates over individual lines in the input data file, we determine the corresponding point type with

   ```
   `point_type = plot->varcolor?((int)plot->varcolor[i]-1):plot->lp_properties.p_type;`
   ```

   This ensures that if we don't use `lc var` then the point type is determined by `pt` (or default). If `lc var` is active, the point type is taken from the corresponding data column in the input data file.
4. call `(*t->pointsize)(plot->lp_properties.p_size);` sets the desired point size specified with `ps` (or default).
5. finally, calls of the type `(*t->point)(x0, y0, point_type);` augment individual line segments with the points.

Comment: Clear and beautiful add-on! Did you make a merge request of this feature to the current `gnuplot`?